# Rendering Layout in the right time

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have this application with several regions and one layout using Backbone Marionette, from time to time I have this problem of creating an ItemView refering its el to dom element that is yet to be rendered, I usually work it out with some rendering calls here and there but it doesnt feel right. So I gues my question is when to render the layout, should i render it explicitly, should i show the regions first and then render the layout or the other way around,

this is the relevant part of my code, as you can see im calling explcitly the render method on the layout and then im showing the regions, not sure if this is the right way to do things:

```
AllegroWidget.addInitializer(function (options) {

                // load templates and append them as scripts
                inject_template("/js/ordering-widget/tpl/combined.html");

                // create app layout using the skeleton
                var AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
                    el: "#allegro-ordering-widget",
                    template: "#template-skeleton",
                    regions: {
                        checkout: "#allegro-checkout",
                        wizard: "#allegro-checkout-wizard",
                        categories: "#allegro-categories-content"
                    }
                });

                AllegroWidget.layout = new AppLayout();
                AllegroWidget.layout.render();

                // Initialize the service providet model, categories and models
                // @todo move this code to a marionette controller when things get messier
                //var _category_collection = new CategoryCollection();
                var _service_provider_model = new ServiceProviderModel;
                _service_provider_model.fetch({
                    headers: { 'X-ApiKey': window.XApiKey },
                    success: function (response) {

                        // Create the user model and categories collection
                        var _user_model;
                        var _user = window.localStorage.getItem("user");
                        if ((_user != null) && (_user != "undefined") ) {
                            _user = JSON.parse(_user);
                            _user_model = new UserModel({ id: _user.id });
                            _user_model.fetch({
                                headers: { 'X-ApiKey': window.XApiKey },
                                success: function (response) {
                                    _user_model.set({ logged: true });
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            _user_model = new UserModel();
                        }
                        // make the model available globaly, mainly for the facebook login
                        window._user_model = _user_model;

                        var _categories_collection = response.get("categories");

                        // create the views
                        var _cateogories_view = new CategoryCollectionView({
                            api_key: window.XApiKey,
                            collection: _categories_collection
                        });

                        var _order_model = new OrderModel;

                        var _wizard_vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
                        // make the wizard event availablt globally, for the facebook login as well
                        window._wizard_vent = _wizard_vent;
                        var _order_wizard_layout = new OrderWizardLayout({
                            user: _user_model,
                            service_provider_model: _service_provider_model,
                            wizard_vent: _wizard_vent,
                            rgns: {
                                account: true,
                                lp: (_service_provider_model.get("modules").findWhere({ hash: "loyalty-points" }) != null),
                                delivery: true,
                                payment: true,
                                thankyou: true
                            }
                        });


                        var _checkout_view = new CheckoutView({
                            collection: _order_model.get("order_items"),
                            order: _order_model,
                            service_provider_model: _service_provider_model,
                            user: _user_model,
                            categories_collection: _categories_collection,
                            order_wizard_itemview: _order_wizard_layout
                        });

                        AllegroWidget.layout.categories.show(_cateogories_view);
                        AllegroWidget.layout.checkout.show(_checkout_view);
                        AllegroWidget.layout.wizard.show(_order_wizard_layout);

                        _order_wizard_layout.render();

                        _order_wizard_layout.account.show(new WizardAccountView({
                            user: _user_model,
                            wizard_vent: _wizard_vent
                        }));

                        if ( _.has(_order_wizard_layout,"lp")) {
                            _order_wizard_layout.lp.show(new WizardLoyaltyPointsView({
                                lp: _service_provider_model.get("loyalty_points"),
                                categories: _service_provider_model.get("categories"),
                                paths: _service_provider_model.get("paths"),
                                wizard_vent: _wizard_vent,
                                order: _order_model,
                                user: _user_model
                            }));
                        } 

                        _order_wizard_layout.delivery.show(new WizardDeliveryView({
                            order: _order_model,
                            countries: _service_provider_model.get("countries"),
                            branches: _service_provider_model.get("branches"),
                            country: _service_provider_model.get("country"),
                            user: _user_model,
                            wizard_vent: _wizard_vent
                        }));

                        var _wizard_receipt_model = new WizardThankYouModel;
                        _order_wizard_layout.payment.show(new WizardPaymentView({
                            wizard_vent: _wizard_vent,
                            user: _user_model,
                            order: _order_model,
                            receipt: _wizard_receipt_model,
                            module_lp: _.has(_order_wizard_layout, "lp")
                        }));
                        _order_wizard_layout.thankyou.show(new WizardThankYouView({
                            wizard_vent: _wizard_vent,
                            receipt_message: _service_provider_model.get("tpl_order_receipt"),
                            model: _wizard_receipt_model
                        }));


                        // Masonry it
                        jQuery('#categories-container').isotope({
                            // options
                            itemSelector: '.category',
                            masonry: {
                                columnWidth: 410
                            }
                        });




                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by creating a main region, covering the application DOM,  that is responsible for rendering the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an "on show" listener on the layout to render the layout's views. You can see an implementation of that solution here :https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L43

Notice that we create the layout instance, as well as the views it will display. Then, when the layout is shown, we have the layout's regions display the proper views.